# How to set the class name on click using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this list in my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Here I want that only the clicked `<li>` should have class set as "active". Hence when someone clicks on second `<li>` element that should be set with class as active and the first should be removed.

How can do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the class from the selected element and add the new:

```
$('li').click(function(){
  $('li.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
     $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul').on('click','li',function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});​
```

[Try the demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/CGmkz/1/)

In this method only *one click listener* will be added to the ul element. It's good for your performance.

I hope this will solve your problem. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks